# removeFromSuperview() not always working

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I declare a UIView variable called var progressBar : UIView?

and I show it or hide the view with this function

```
func showProgressBar(showBar: Bool){
if showBar{
            let viewHeight = view.frame.size.height
            progressBar = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("progressBar", owner: nil, options: nil)?.first as? UIView
            progressBar?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: viewHeight - 80 , width: self.view.frame.width, height: 80)
            if let bar = progressBar{
                self.view.addSubview(bar)
            }
        }else{
            DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                self.progressBar?.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
```

Sometimes when I navigate a bit between the views I am not able to hide the progress bar, even when `self.progressBar?.removeFromSuperview()` is executed. It looks to me like if the view has lost the reference to the old progress bar... Do you have an idea about the problem and how I could fix it?

Comment: try removing progressBar directly in else cond. I think there is no need of removing it in DispathQueue.main.async()

Comment: I added  DispatchQueue.main.async() to see if it solves the problem. Also without it the problem remain.

Comment: hiding the progressBar doesn't works ?

Comment: No, same problem, sometimes work sometimes not

Comment: can you please share your complete class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to show and hide your `progressBar` why don't you use `self.progressBar.hidden = true/false`? By doing so, you can just create your `progressBar` once and `removeFromSuperview` once you don't use it anymore.

```
func showProgressBar(showBar: Bool){
    if showBar {
        // Check this first
        if progressBar == nil {
            let viewHeight = view.frame.size.height
            progressBar = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("progressBar", owner: nil, options: nil)?.first as? UIView
            progressBar?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: viewHeight - 80 , width: self.view.frame.width, height: 80)
            if let bar = progressBar {
                self.view.addSubview(bar)
            }
        }
    } else {
        DispatchQueue.main.async() {
            self.progressBar?.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought about it but the progressBar will be very rarely shown to the user, so I thought,from a performance view,  it don't make sense to have it always hidden in the app

Comment: It's likely that you create a new `progressBar` while the existing one is still there. You should firstly check whether it's been deallocated before creating a new one.

Comment: Thank you. Will it also make sense to make the class ProgressBar as a singleton?

Comment: Yes, I normally implement it that way

Comment: Strange that you add the subview on the same thread as the method is called, but you shift to the main queue explicitly to remove the subview. This explicit async call is probably not needed.

Answer (score 7):

If you're calling showProgressBar twice, it's not validated that there's not a bar already, so you could be adding a second one and losing a reference to the first one. Thus, when you remove it, it just removes the second one and doesn't work.